# pulling records with python

Tags: python, json, api, airtable

Having some trouble with this. I know that I have to use the offset value to pull more than 100 records, here is what I currently have:

```
AIRTABLE_BASE_ID = 'airtablebaseid'
AIRTABLE_API_KEY = 'airtableapikey'
AIRTABLE_TABLE_NAME = 'airtablename'
endpoint = f'https://api.airtable.com/v0/{AIRTABLE_BASE_ID}/{AIRTABLE_TABLE_NAME}?filterByFormula=AND(NOT(%7BSent+to+Payroll%7D+%3D+%22Sent%22)%2CNOT(%7BSent+to+Payroll%7D+%3D+%22Skipped%22))'

def get_airtable():
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {AIRTABLE_API_KEY}"
    }

    response = requests.get(endpoint,  headers=headers)
    return response

recordList = []
recordIDs = []
recordTimeStamp = []

response = get_airtable()
data = response.json()
for record in data['records']:
    recordList.append(record['fields'])
    recordIDs.append(record['id'])
    recordTimeStamp.append(record['createdTime'])
    print(record)
```

Answer (score 1):

Airtable can't give you more than 100 records per request, it works, as you said it, with pagination and offset.

The first request you made without `offset` parameter will return you a payload with a `offset` field set to `n`, you have to pass that offset to your next request to get the `n` next records, and so on...

```
response = get_airtable()
data = response.json()
OFFSET = data['offset'] #not sur if "offset" is at root of the response

endpoint = f'https://api.airtable.com/v0/{AIRTABLE_BASE_ID}/{AIRTABLE_TABLE_NAME}?offset={OFFSET}&filterByFormula=AND(NOT(%7BSent+to+Payroll%7D+%3D+%22Sent%22)%2CNOT(%7BSent+to+Payroll%7D+%3D+%22Skipped%22))'
```